# How to display in the combo box only those elements that are not in the table C#

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, datagrid

I want to display in Combobox only those elements, that do not exist in a table column.

My table:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding MainRows, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
  CanUserAddRows="True"
  >
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="2*"  Header="Agent"  >
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate >
            <DataTemplate>
                <ComboBox  
                    SelectedItem="{Binding Item, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.AvaibleAgents, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}">
                <ComboBox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

User can add agent just one time. a want to remove from combobox items, those exist in datagrid
My DataContext VM

```
public class  MainDocumentVM : CCRDocumentVM
{
    public  MainDocumentVM(CCRMainDocument innerValue) : base(innerValue)
    {
    }

public List<MainRowVM> _MainRows;
public List<MainRowVM> MainRows
{
    get
    {
        //TODO: Refactor it ASAP
        if (MainRows == null)
        {
            _ccrMainRows = (InnerValue as MainDocument).MainRows.Select(x => new MainRowVM(x)).ToList();
        }
        return _MainRows.Where(x=>x.InnerValue.IsActive).ToList();
    }
}
#region Functionality
private MainRowVM _selectedRow;

public MainRowVM SelectedRow
{
    get { return _selectedRow; }
    set
    {
        _selectedRow = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}


public ICommand AddNewRowCommand
{
    get
    {
         return Commands.GetOrCreateCommand(() => AddNewRowCommand,(() => AddNewRow(CCRMainRow.CreateNew<MainRow>())));
    }
}


public void AddNewRow(MainRow row)
{
        (InnerValue as MainDocument).CCRMainRows.Add(row);
        if (_MainRows != null)
        {
            MainRows.Add(new MainRowVM(row));
        }
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MainRows));
        //OnPropertyChanged(nameof(AvaibleItems));
}

public List<Agents> AvaibleAgents
{
    get
    {
        return ManagerFactoryResolver.CurrentFactory.CCRAgentsManager.AllValues
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

}

My ViewModel of Rows:

```
public class MainRowVM : EditableDataVM<MainRow>
{
    public MainRowVM(MainRow innervalue) : base(innervalue)
    {  }

    public Agent Agent
    {
        get
        {
            return ManagerFactoryResolver.CurrentFactory.AgentManager
                .AllValues.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == InnerValue.AgentID);
        }    
        set
        {
            InnerValue.AgentID = value.Id;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

Comment: are you using MVVM? Please post your ViewModel code as well

Comment: Your question is too broad. But you should look at `CollectionViewSource` for your `AvaibleAgents` collection, so you can impose filtering.

Comment: sorry, now I'm try add some VM. 
You advice look like what I'm need

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to update the AvailableAgents list in your VM each time the user add an agent, deleting the agend just added...

Answer (score 0):

You should filter out those elements with any logic you'd choose to in your ViewModel and expose them with a property (for example, a property called `ExcludedItems`) and then bind the `ComboBox.ItemsSource` to that property. Each time you update the collection / table, raise property changed on that property to reflect the changes in the ComboBox too.

A few things to note though - When Binding, you don't necessarily have to use the `DataContext.` prefix, only the property itself since the current DataContext is always the data context.

Comment: If i remove item from collection in combobox list, this cant be show in combobox on View, and throw exception.

Comment: What's the exception you get?

Comment: I cent remove from itemsource item, if them binding to row..
I get some like "selected item is null" becouse it be delete from datasource if it add to datagrid.
Paradox)